# Model acts as if it has no code in it on staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have the following model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base  
  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :kind, in: [:functional, :technical], predicates: true
  belongs_to :ration
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :group_animal_keys
  has_many :animal_keys, through: :group_animal_keys

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_animal_keys
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :animal_keys

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :ration_id, presence: true, if: :functional_group?

  scope :functional_groups, -> {where(kind: :functional)}
  scope :technical_groups, -> {where(kind: :technical)}

  def functional_group?
    kind == 'functional'
  end
end
```

Ever since I deployed (with a standard Capistrano setup) to our server, this model behaves like it has no code in it. I can create an instance, but `Group.new.valid?` returns `true`, `Group.first.ration` gives an `undefined method ration`. `Group.functional_groups` also returns an `undefined method published`.

Any idea what might go wrong? The model behaves normal in development.

Comment: How do you connect to your rails console on your server? Are you specifying the right environment? (`bundle exec rails s -e staging`). Do you have a correct `database.yml` with the staging parameters?

Comment: The console on my server I access via `bundle exec rails c staging`. Yes, `database.yml` is correct. It's also only this model that behaves this way. Other models act normal.

Comment: Could you then post this model if it's the only one not working?

Comment: Very little information to understand what could be wrong! Can you post the code ? Are you by any chance skipping model validation in your code ?

Comment: I have added the model.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

There was another, empty `group.rb` somewhere within the app folder for some reason, that also inherited from `ActiveRecord`.